# Parsing XML using elt.xpath in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML document using elt.xpath in python.

```
eventId = elt.xpath('id/text()')
homeTeam = elt.xpath('./homeTeam/name/text()')
awayTeam = elt.xpath('./awayTeam/name/text()')
homeTeamOdds = elt.xpath('./periods/period/moneyLine/homePrice/text()')
awayTeamOdds = elt.xpath('./periods/period/moneyLine/awayPrice/text()')
```

I then zip the lists together:

```
full_iterator = zip(eventId, homeTeam, awayTeam, homeTeamOdds, awayTeamOdds)
```

However, some events have no moneyline odds so they have no

```
/periods/period/moneyLine/awayPrice/text() 
/periods/period/moneyLine/homePrice/text()
```

Which means the lists are then uneven causing issues with the zipping. Is it possible to if there is no odds to pad the list?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I would iterate over all events and gather the event parameter using context-specific search inside each particular event:

```
from lxml import etree

url = "http://dlewis.ie/pinnacle_feed.xml"

tree = etree.parse(url)

events = []
for event in tree.xpath('//event'):
    eventId = event.findtext('id')
    homeTeam = event.findtext('./homeTeam/name')
    awayTeam = event.findtext('./awayTeam/name')
    homeTeamOdds = event.findtext('./periods/period/moneyLine/homePrice')
    awayTeamOdds = event.findtext('./periods/period/moneyLine/awayPrice')
    events.append([eventId, homeTeam, awayTeam, homeTeamOdds, awayTeamOdds])

print events
```

This would print:

```
[
    ['445413593', 'CD Lugo', 'Barcelona-B', '2.02', '3.93'], 
    ['445413595', 'Racing Santander', 'Osasuna', '2.97', '2.73'],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Would that not add padding to the bottom of the list. In my case it could be 
event1 has odds 2.3 & 2.4 
event2 has no odds and 
event3 has odds 1.2 & 3.4

With izip_longest would the result not be [event1, 2.3, 2.4] [event2, 1.2, 3.4] and [event3, none, none]?

Comment: @Vuzuggu I think it would be `[event1, 2.3, 2.4]`, `[event2, None, None]` and `[event3, 1.2, 3.4]` - note that you can configure smth else instead of `None` by setting `fillvalue` keyword argument.

Comment: I can't seem to get that approach to work at all. I end up with everything being None except the eventid. The problem is, in my limited experience, the list containing the odds simply ignores the fact there is no odds there. So the zip has no way of knowing which odds are to do with which events. I would need a null/0/none etc stored into the odds list for this to work.

Comment: @Vuzuggu thank you for the explanation, you are right, `izip_longest()` would not help here. Could you provide an example XML data?

Comment: @Vuzuggu thank you for providing the XML source, please see the update. Hope that helps.